# 2003 mazda 6 won't move or go into gear

Tags: engine, automatic-transmission, mazda-6

I was driving this vehicle on the highway going home. All of a sudden I noticed the oil light coming on, battery light came on too and I could not go past 60mph. So I suddenly pulled over and as soon and I pulled over the car just shut down/off and did not crank back up. Got it towed home. Long story short before this even happened I was informed I had a weak engine so I got a used low mile engine installed. Car cranks up but will not go into gear or move. What could be the problem?

Comment: Did you check the linkage to the transmission? Make sure it didn't get dislodged or something? *How* is it not going into gear? Will the gearshift move at all? Engine *does* run fine?